# SQL Server: stored procedure not working when called from python

Tags: python, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I've a simple table called `Points` with two columns `QuestionID` and `UserID`:

```
QuestionID  UserID
-------------------
5            2
6            1
```

I wrote a stored procedure to insert data into this table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetPoints] 
     @QuestionID INT, 
     @UserID INT 
AS
     INSERT INTO dbo.Points (QuestionID, UserID)
     VALUES (@QuestionID, @UserID)
```

I executed this procedure and it seems to be working fine.

Then I wrote Python code to connect to this database and execute this procedure.

```
import pyodbc as po
    
# Connection variables
server = '################'
database = '#############'
username = '#############'
password = '################'
    
# Connection string
cnxn = po.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
            server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD=' + password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# Prepare the stored procedure execution script and parameter values
storedProc = "EXEC SetPoints @QuestionID = ?, @UserID = ?"
params = (2, 3)
    
# Execute stored procedure with parameters
cursor.execute(storedProc, params)

# Close the cursor and delete it
cursor.close()
del cursor
    
# Close the database connection
cnxn.close()
```

When I run the `Execute` the Python code shows no errors, but if I check the `Points` table, nothing is inserted....

Can somebody tell me what's going on? The procedure works fine in SSMS but when I execute it from Python, nothing happens.

Comment: What is the `implicit_transactions` setting? `SELECT 2 & @@OPTIONS` result should be `0`? If it's `2` then it is on incorrectly

Comment: @Charlieface It's OFF..Is that why it's not working ? `SELECT @ & @@OPTIONS` returns 0. So, i guess that's not the problem ?

Comment: No should be off, must be something else. Are you **sure** there is no error? Is that **all** your code, are you opening a transaction somewhere (`select @@trancount;` should be 0)?

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for your help. I solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:
The solution was to add `auto_commit=True` to the `pyodbc.connect()` function.
I found the answer from another post on this site.

Comment: Interesting. `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` is the same as `auto_commit=off`. That's kinda wierd that instead of pyodbc using that official option it appears to take it's own transaction manually.